# compression washer tap valve too big?

Tags: faucet, valve

This is an odd one! I have a bathroom sink where the hot tap has a compression valve. I can easily loosen the valve but I cannot then remove it from the tap! It seems that the far end of the compression valve is wider/as wide as the thread of the valve. Is this a recognised issue? Is there any way of removing this valve, or do I need to replace the whole tap? I can provide an image if required!

Comment: Pics are always helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, pictures are good to support your questions. Depending on valve, sometimes you need a special tool. But yes, post pictures. You may require to pull hard on valve or tap, depending on how it’s grip better. Due to water hardness valve can be stuck hard.

Comment: @Hemant_Surti. Thanks! I applied a little more brute force and ignorance and managed to remove it. Was a little too wary of breaking something before. I've replaced the valve and may try cleaning the old one (it made a grating noise everytime it was turned off)

Comment: I use this every time I work on plumbing or on valve (not good for rubber gasket) https://www.homedepot.com/p/Oatey-1-oz-Plumber-s-Grease-30620/203489444